# Exception Catch and CallHook

Tags: php, exception, autoload

I'm using a callhook to execute my classes and methods in my MVC framework. No i would like to add so error-handling with the PHP Exception Function. I'm just wondering where to it is the best place to execute the catch command. A request can (of course) lead to the execution of multiple classes. Throughout the system exceptions are made. (example is mentioned below).

```
function callHook() {
    global $urlArray;
    //DEFINE CONTROLLERS
    if (strlen(strstr($urlArray[0],'popup_'))>0)
    {
        $controller = substr($urlArray[0], 6);
    }
    else
    {
        $controller = $urlArray[0]; 
    }
    $queryString[] = $urlArray[1];
    $URLaction = $urlArray[2];

    if(!isset($controller) && empty($controller)){ $controller = 'home';}
    if(!isset($URLaction) || empty($URLaction)){$action = 'view';}else{$action = $URLaction;}

    $controllerName = str_replace('-','', $controller);
    $controller = ucwords($controller);
    $model = rtrim($controller, 's');
    $controller .= 'Controller';
    $dispatch = new $controller($model,$controllerName,$action);

    if ((int)method_exists($controller, $action)) {
        $ResultArray = call_user_func_array(array($dispatch,$action),$queryString);
        return $ResultArray;
    } else {
        exit("FATAL ERROR: 101.".$controller."-".$action);
    }
}
```

Example Class:

```
public function CheckCarExistance(){
    if(!is_object($this-> carId)){throw new Exception("carId is missing!");}
        $CountCars = new modelmysql();
        $CountCars->connect();
        $CountCars->count('system_cars', "carId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($this-> carId)."'");
        $this->results = $CountCars ->getResult();

}
```

To display all the exceptions would it be a good idea to place the try/catch in the call hook or just in every class/method?

Callhook

```
if ((int)method_exists($controller, $action)) {
        try{
            $ResultArray = call_user_func_array(array($dispatch,$action),$queryString);
            return $ResultArray;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
          echo 'Error Found message: ' .$e->getMessage() .' <br />\n";';
        }

    } else {
        exit("FATAL ERROR: 101.".$controller."-".$action);
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you to place `try/catch` in the entry point where you dispatch your request. So in this case you can throw exceptions in your code and catch them in one place and log them in the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would do in this way

```
try{
    if ((int)method_exists($controller, $action)) {
        throw new Exception("FATAL ERROR: 101.".$controller."-".$action);
    }
    $ResultArray = call_user_func_array(array($dispatch,$action),$queryString);
    return $ResultArray;
} catch(Exception $e){
   exit( 'FATAL ERROR: ' .$e->getMessage() .' <br />\n"');
}
```